# Warning error when using Enzyme inside beforeEach in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, enzyme

This is my code right now:

```
const Component = () => (
  <Provider store={storeRedux}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Context.Provider value={...}}>
        <Mode { ...props } />
      </Context.Provider>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>
);
```

There is no error in that code but the warning is in this part below:

```
  describe('Test Parent', () => {
  let wrapper;
  beforeEach(() => {
      wrapper = mount(<Component />);
    });
    afterEach(() => {
      wrapper.unmount();
    });
  })
//Variable 'wrapper' implicitly has type 'any' in some locations where its type cannot be determined.ts(7034)
```

The test is working but is there any workarounds here to make the warning go away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it to work by adding `ReactWrapper` into the `let wrapper`:

```
let wrapper:ReactWrapper
```